# How to use parent viewcontroller to launch uiactionsheet so that it does not get clipped?

Tags: iphone, ios

Hey so I have a problem where I am inserting an actionsheet into a view that is inside of a scrollview in a different view controller. The actionsheet works just fine, the problem is that if i go down at all in the scrollview the actionsheet gets clipped off. I've tried several solutions with no luck. I think the problem is that the actionsheet is being inserted into the view that is placed inside the scrollview. Anyone have any idea how to launch the action sheet from the view controller that the scrollview is in instead? Here is how I am trying to do it right now:

When a button is touched it calls this method:

```
- (IBAction)callDP:(id)sender {

    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    datePickerView.tag = 10;

    [datePickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [actionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];
    [actionSheet setTitle:@"Start Date"];        
    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];


    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;


   //THIS IS THE PART THAT I THINK I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM WITH 

   // [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.toolbarItems];
    //[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];


}
```

Here is where I insert the view into the scrollview. I have it set up so that I am using a view from a different uiviewcontroller class to control everything. The reason I do that is so that i can have the scrollable part, but be able to visually create everything that I need without having to do it programmatically....I apologize if that is kind of confusing. I can clarify if needs be...but here it is. The viewcontroller class that contains the view I want to put into the scroll view is called registration page. Its inside of registrationPage that it calls the actionSheet. Let me know what you think...

```
registrationPage = [[RegistrationPageToInsertViewController alloc]init];

    viewToInsert = registrationPage.view;

    [scrollView addSubview:viewToInsert];
    [scrollView setContentSize:viewToInsert.frame.size];
//    [scrollView sendSubviewToBack:imgView];

    //scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,416);
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
```

Here are a couple of screenshots to help you see what I'm talking about:
[image: This is what happens when you click on the button while its at the bottom of the screen]

[image: This is what happens when i scroll down a little bit on the screen and then push the birthdate button]

Comment: A visual example (image/s) might help understanding your posting.

Comment: @Till is right.We dont understand why do you use "viewToInsert" view.because already a view is there.You have to add your scrollView on that view and put all other UI components in scrollView.there is no big deal

Comment: instead of this line [actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view]; try like this.[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

Comment: I tried that in the begining and it didn't work. The problem I think is that I am inserting this view into another view so that I can make it scrollable. Thats a problem I think because then the actionsheet is inserted into the first view and therefore when you scrolldown...it clips it off

Comment: @R.A Good thinking though, i appreciate you looking at it still the same. I am trying to acess the viewcontroller that the view was inserted into...i added some images to help...

Comment: hey hey @Rmyers just do as i say.You have a nib or viewController. Whatever. Just add a scrollView as subView to what you have.Then you just add all your textfields, labels and all will be subview of scrollView.this is the correct way to do that.if you present action sheet,you have to show that in self.View only.

Comment: @R.A That more or less does solve the problem. I have a couple others to deal with now but this particular one is solved thanks. If you want to write it up as an answer I'll set yours as the answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this line

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];
```

try like this.

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Just do as i say.You have a nib or viewController. Whatever. Just add a scrollView as subView to what you have.Then you just add all your textfields, labels and all will be subview of scrollView.this is the correct way to do that.if you present action sheet,you have to show that in self.View only.

Comment: You were right. I was going about it completely wrong. When I fixed it so everything was a subview of the main view controller everything worked great. Thanks for the answer

Comment: As a side note....I figured out that you can unlock the views in the storyboards so that you can make adjustments to extra big stuff if you want to use it in scrollview or something...Note to anyone else experiencing a similar problem.